# Chrome footer bug

Tags: google-chrome, footer

I have got a problem with Chrome.
I have been building a webpage for a Community and there is a strange bug in Chrome.
This site has the pages in two different language(Hungarian & English).
All Hungarian & English pages have the same HTML structure and use the same CSS file.
Against this the pages in English language have problem with the footer.
You can not see but only the half of it.

Here are two links to compare:
http://lpvphoto2.webspace.virginmedia.com/lessons.html (hungarian one)
http://lpvphoto2.webspace.virginmedia.com/lessonsen.html (english one).

There is no any error like this in IE or FF.
But there is the same problem on Android Chrome as well.

Thank you

Laszlo

Comment: Please add screenshots of the specific problem. Links will eventually change over time, making this question less useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this file:
http://lpvphoto2.webspace.virginmedia.com/javascript/menucontentsen.js

I downloaded your page locally and didn't have problems with the English footer until I included that file.

Comment: That is strange. All pages uses the same files including this anylinkmenu.js file as well. It should cause a problem to the hungarian pages as well. Or can be something else cause this problem to the english pages?

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in the file menucontentsen.js. Because not I wrote this script I forgot to take out one line. Thank you very much.